# How do I escape a reserved word in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

In scala one can use backticks (`) as illustrated below:

match is a reserved word so the following will not compile:

```
class Foo(var match: String)
```

but this will:

```
class Foo(var `match`: String)
```

Similar to the above, what does one do to escape reserved words in AS3 in the example above without using dynamic properties?

Comment: For use in what, identifiers?

Comment: This depends heavily on the context, I would think.

Comment: Updated the question with an example.

Comment: don't use reserved words? prepend with '_'?

Answer (score 1):

It is normally not recommended to use reserved words as part of your variables, function names, function parameters or Class names. Why? Because as in any language reserved words are meant to only be used for specific uses.

You can also always add another small word in camel case to differentiate your variable from the reserved word.

Comment: Well, the question isn't if I 'should' use reserved words.

Comment: This is required for a code generator component which generates code from some metadata for a couple of languages. The metadata somes from multiple sources may have reserved words in it which need to be treated as variables/functions. Like I mentioned in my question, languages like Scala allow escaping.

Comment: So you are generating code via an AS class? If this is the case is there any particular reason in why you want to name variables exactly like reserved words?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with posting variables to paypal. For example:

```
URLData.return = "mystring";
```

won't work because return is a reserve word. So simply use:

```
URLData.['return'] = "mystring";
```